# Jquery .html() and .attr() to populate P tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to populate `<p>` tags with content based on their class. Here's my code:

```
<p class="header"></p>
<p class="desc"></p>
```

```javascript
var header = 'header content here';
var desc = 'description content here';

var id = $("p").attr("class");

$("p." + id).html(id);
```

By using `.html(id)`, I'm trying to call the content stored in the variables with the same name as the `class` of the `<p>` tag. However, this method only returns

```
<p>header</p>
```

and

```
<p>desc</p>
```

as opposed to pulling the content from the variables.

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery isn't magic - no method in JavaScript can just find a variable in your current scope with that name. The best way to solve this is to put your data inside an object:

```
var data = {
    header: 'I am a header',
    desc:   'I am a description'
};
```

Then, you can access an element with `data[id]`:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('class');

    if(id in data) {
        $this.html(data[id]);
    }
});
```

Or, if you like JavaScript:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var i, p;

for(i = 0; p = paragraphs[i]; i++) {
    if(p.className in data) {
        p.innerHTML = data[p.className];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to duplicate your answer in the second half of mine: when the warning came up about new answers being posted I only saw Horatio's - guess I didn't scroll down far enough.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you don't really have a way of referencing your variables easily. The way to have named items in JavaScript that you can reference, is to use an ["Object literal"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_literals). This allows you to access data using a "key". For example, an object literal looks like:

```
var myObj = { "keyname" : "value for key" };
```

We can then access the information using dot notation:

```
console.log(myObj.keyname); // value for key
```

But the neat thing is you can use square bracket notation to access items using a variable:

```
key = "keyname";
console.log(myObj[key]); // value for key
```

So, to answer you question, try the following:

```
var myContent, myClass, txt;

myContent = {
    "header" : "header content here",
    "desc"   : "description content here"
}
myClass = $("p").attr("class");
txt     = myContent[myClass];
$("p."+id).html(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` variable will contain a string with the name of the element's class. This string has no relationship with the `header` and `desc` variables.

I think another way of putting your requirement is that you want to loop through the paragraph elements on the page and set their content according to their class. The following will work *if they only have one class each*:

```
var header = 'header content here';
var desc = 'description content here' ;

$("p.header,p.desc").html(function() {
   return this.className === "header" ? header : desc;
});
```

Note that `this.className` is equivalent to but more efficient than `$(this).attr("class")`.

The above selects all paragraph elements that have either class, and then sets their content depending on which class. You could also do this:

```
$("p.header").html(header);
$("p.desc").html(desc);
```

Or you can do a more generic solution:

```
var content = {
   "header" : "header content here",
   "desc"   : "description content here"
};

$("p").each(function() {
   var newContent = content[this.className];
   if (newContent)
      $(this).html(newContent);
});
```

With the last method you can add more items to `content` and they will be applied automatically with no change to the `.each()` loop.